# Why is textarea not editable in fullscreen mode?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullscreen

I am using the following jquery plugin to enable fullscreen in my web app.

https://github.com/martinaglv/jQuery-FullScreen

It works great, except that when I am in fullscreen mode my textarea is not editable? Why is this? Is it a browser thing or the plugin?

It doesnt seem to be disabled in any way...

My test code below:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/martinaglv/jQuery-FullScreen/master/fullscreen/jquery.fullscreen.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <textarea></textarea>
        <button>
            Go Go Fullscreen</button>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function () {

            if ($.support.fullscreen) {

                $('button').click(function (e) {

                    $('#content').fullScreen();

                });
            }

        })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a workaround (for Chrome, at least), but I don't know how it factors into the plug-in you're using. You have to pass along a little instruction to allow keyboard input:

```
document.body.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
```

**UPDATE:**

You could modify the plug-in pretty easily. This function would change to reflect the above:

```
function requestFullScreen(elem){
    if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
        elem.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
        elem.webkitRequestFullScreen();
    }
}
```

By default, the plug-in forces the browser to enter full-screen mode without allowing keyboard input.

[More information here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_full-screen_mode) from MDN, and [the thread](https://github.com/marijnh/CodeMirror/issues/733) where I found some clues.

Answer (score 0):

From the tutorial:

The idea of allowing developers to programatically take up the user screen doesn’t come without serious security implications, which is why keyboard usage is limited. Of course, there are many legitimate uses for keyboard input in full screen, which is going to be addressed in future revisions of the API via some kind of permission prompt.

However, even in its current, limited form, the API still gives us an opportunity to enhance the experience of the end user.

It doesn't even go full screen in some browsers, like IE 9.

http://tutorialzine.com/2012/02/enhance-your-website-fullscreen-api/